# How do I get IntelliJ to make new branches based on selected brach not HEAD?

Tags: intellij-idea

Ocassionally I did hard reset on my current working branch. I restored all the changes lost but here I've another issue:

I have main branch named by `dev_security`.
I checkout it, I'm on it.

When I create new branch by selecting new branch from branches menu and give it `test_branch` name

[image]

[image: create new branch]

it  tells me that I've created branch from `HEAD`

[image]

Ok, I've deleted that branch.

When I am creating new branch by selecting the branch and them making new branch from it

[image]

Then it's ok and tells me that branch is created from `dev_security`

[image]

I am pretty sure before my hard reset operation it was the same and ALWAYS told me about creation from `dev_security`. How can I make it to behave the same?

Comment: There is no difference between a branch "created from HEAD" and a branch "created from branch X" if X is the currently checked out branch. What was the problem with the first attempt, besides that you did not like the text in the green box?

Comment: I'm not sure what IntelliJ actually does in the second attempt, but possibly it sets up `origin/dev_security` as a remote-tracking branch for `test_branch` which may not even be what you want.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you for response! I suppose my HEAD may point to another branch and I am sure it always was "created from branch X"

Comment: @mkrieger1 all I want is to make branch BASED on ```dev_security```

Comment: From the picture of the first attempt it seems that you are doing that. There should be no problem. "checked out dev_security" means that HEAD and dev_security are the same.

Comment: @mkrieger1 why then idea signs differs althrough I am always on the same branch and what really differs is the way I create new branch?

Comment: This seems to be a question about using IntelliJ, not a question about using Git. Perhaps you should just use the [tag:intellij] and/or [tag:intellij-idea] tags, so as not to get command-line-Git answers.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset` does not affect checkout action from IntelliJ UI.

In [User Guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html#create-branch) you can see the description of each action.
Therefore it is expected that you observe different behavior for different actions. There is no option to set the same behavior for different actions.

If you would like to see what commands exactly are executed when you perform different actions, then please open Git toolwindow, switch to "Console" tab and see what command exactly are executed.